# Open Web Analytics protect with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, web, password-protection

I am using Piwik and now new Open Web Analytics (also a Tracking Web analytics software) and now I would like to protect the open web analytics folder  with a `.htaccess`. It works with Piwik and doesn't work with Open Web Analytics

The code from the `.htaccess` is the following:

```
# Sample .htaccess file for your web document root

# Restrict outside access
AuthUserFile /../www/analytics.domain.com/httpdocs/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Piwik"
AuthType Basic

<Files "*">
Require valid-user
</Files>

<Files ~ "^piwik\.(js|php)|robots\.txt$">
Allow from all
Satisfy any
</Files>

<Files ~ "^owa\.(js|php)|robots\.txt$">
Allow from all
Satisfy any
</Files>

# Disable session auto-start; incompatible with Zend_Session.
php_flag session.auto_start off

# Disable directory viewing.
Options -All
```

If I want to get access to the Piwik folder, I have to enter the `.htaccess` username and password but if I open the Website that I am tracking I don't need to enter the password. That's how it should also work for OWA. If I open the OWA folder it also aks for name and password but after adding the tracking code to the website, it asks for the name and password everytime I open the Website. So why does it work with piwik and not for OWA?